# What is the best framework for developing facebook applications?

Tags: facebook

I saw some frameworks and wanted to know which one is the best.
Raw PHP, .net, Java...? Another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would answer this question with another question:

- **Which is the language or framework
  you are more comfortable with?**

But if that does not answer your question, and you prefer to try some other language/framework to develop Facebook apps, I believe the best you can do is take a look at the [Facebook developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) site and check which SDK they offer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get a lot of different answers here. Depending on what people prefer to use, they'll say it's the best.As long as you can get what you want done, go with what you know.